# Need a bounce from the direction of the player

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I need the bounce of an object when it collides with the player depending on the direction of the player.

Comment: what is your question? what have you tried? provide some code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a force to the tree in the direction from the player to the tree should do it.

```csharp
Vector3 dir = treeTransform.position - playerTransform.position;
treeRb.AddForce(dir*force, ForceMode.Impulse);
```

If the origin of the tree is off center or the tree doesn't tilt enough you can also use `AddForceAtPosition`

Comment: Is this possible to do without Rigidbody?

Comment: @LinaDev the alternative would be an animation with a bit of turning